# You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with two monitors and an Nvidia 970 Graphics Card.  Things worked fine.  Then I rebooted and now they don't work.  I can only see one monitor.  When I run nvidia-settings, it complains

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
```

My xorg.conf file has:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid question but did you run `nvidia-xconfig` in a terminal? Maybe as `sudo`

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers and rebooted and everything was okay.  Except I'm not okay.  Why did this happen?  Did one of the Ubuntu Software Updates uninstall the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers and rebooted and everything was okay. Except I'm not okay. Why did this happen? Did one of the Ubuntu Software Updates uninstall the Nvidia drivers?